# How do I conclude from $E[X_{+}1_{Y\geq 0}]=0$ that $P(X > 0, Y \leq 0)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, integration, random-variables, expected-value

Let $X_{+}$ be the part of $X$ that is strictly positive.

How do I conclude from $E[X_{+}1_{Y\geq 0}]=0$ that $P(X > 0, Y \leq 0)=0$?

My idea

$0=E[X_{+}1_{Y\geq 0}]=E[X1_{X>0,Y\leq0}]$ and since $X\neq 0$ on $1_{X>0}$ it follows that $P(X>0,Y\leq 0)$

it seems obvious but I do not think my reasoning is up to scratch. Any ideas? Is strictly positive actually necessary here?

Comment: It's important that $X > 0$ on $1_{X >0}$, not just that $X \neq 0$. Other than that your proof looks correct. We can't conclude $P(X \geq 0, Y \leq 0) = 0$ since we can have $X = 0$ identically and $E[X_+ 1_{Y \geq 0}] = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Your claim is wrong. Consider $X$ a random variable with exponential distribution and let $Y=-X$. Then $X_{+}1_{Y\geq 0} = 0$ a.s., thus $E(X_{+}1_{Y\geq 0} )=0$. However $$P(X>0\cap Y\leq 0) = P(X>0)=1 $$

The only thing you can derive from $E(X_{+}1_{Y\geq 0} )=0$ is $X_{+}1_{Y\geq 0}$ a.s., which is equivalent to $(X>0 \implies Y<0)$ a.s. Hence 
$$\begin{aligned}
P(X>0\cap Y\leq 0) &= E(1_{X>0}1_{Y\leq 0})\\
&= E(1_{X>0}1_{Y< 0}) + E(1_{X>0}1_{Y= 0})\\
&= E(1_{X>0}) \\
&=P(X>0)
\end{aligned}$$